# Reading from TextFile in C++

Tags: c++, c

I am a java/C# developer and i am trying to write a C or C++ code to read data from a text file. this is very easily done in java and c# but not in c or c++.

the textfile i am reading looks like this:

```
a,b,c,d,e
1,0,1,1,0
0,1,1,0,0
0,0,0,1,1
```

i need to store the values in 2 arrays.
the 1st one is a 1D char array which will contain: `a b c d e`
the 2nd one is a 2D bool array which will contain:

```
  1 0 1 1 0
  0 1 1 0 0
  0 0 0 1 1
```

how can i do this?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415515/) may contain some useful information.

Comment: C or C++? the answers are (I think), or at least can be, very very different. Also, the "a,b,c,d,e" in your example will always be made up of single characters (ie no "foo,bar,baz,qux,quux")?

Comment: I would recommend storing inside a vector, it would give you a lot more flexibility if you want to switch it up later.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you at least make an attempt at what you are trying to do, to help you get started, here is a basic read out of the example data you provided. This example should be simple enough to allow you to expand it to meet other data sets.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    const int n_letters = 5;

    const int n_columns = 5;
    const int n_rows = 3;

    char letters[n_letters];
    bool booleans[n_rows][n_columns];

    std::ifstream stream("myfile.txt");
    if (stream) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n_letters; ++i) {
            stream >> letters[i];
            std::cout << letters[i] << ',';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
        for (int i = 0; i < n_rows; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n_columns; ++j) {
                stream >> booleans[i][j];
                std::cout << booleans[i][j] << ',';
            }
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Reads the following text:

```
a b c d e
1 0 1 1 0
0 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 1
```

And outputs:

```
a,b,c,d,e
1,0,1,1,0
0,1,1,0,0
0,0,0,1,1
```

Comment: you should use a two dimensional array for numbers, since that's what the op asked for(2D == two dimensions).

Comment: @Shinnok, fixed as per the OP's spec

Answer (score 0):

A first comment: when parsing a file, it's often useful to read
the file line by line, and then parse each line, using
std::istringstream, or boost::regex, or whatever other technique
you please.  I like boost::regex, because it immediately
indicates if there is a syntax error, but carefully designed,
istream can as well.

The first thing, in any case, is to specify more precisely the
formats: Is there always just one letter? Are the numbers always
Just 0 and 1?  Are there always exactly five values per line?
Until we know that, it's rather difficult to say more.