# CSV data into Form control

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I'm using the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/556754/761170) to read a CSV file, and I want to assign the `const CSVRow& row` value to a form control (e.g. a `ListBox`). How can I accomplish this?

Here's the code I'd like to change:

```
void display(const CSVRow& row)
{
    if(!row.size()) return;
    CSVRowCI i = row.begin();
    std::cout << *(i++); 
    for(; i != row.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << ',' << *i;
}
```

But instead of `std::cout << ',' << *i`, I want to do:

```
this->ListBox1->Items->Add(*i);
```

I tried using `*i.ToString()`, but it gives me an error:

> Cannot convert const std::basic string  to System::String

Comment: Duplicate of the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120140/csv-parser-in-c

Answer (score 0):

I see that the type `CSVRowCI` is actually a `typedef` representing an individual `std::string` element in a `std::vector` of `std::strings`.Since you want to use this code in a C++/CLI WinForms application, you'd need to convert it to a `System.String` first (since that's what the `Add()` method is expecting). Perhaps you could do something along the lines of:

```
String^ myString= gcnew String(*i.c_str());
myListBox->Items->Add(myString);
```

I'm not very familiar with C++/CLI so, there probably are better ways to convert a `std::string` to `System.String`.

Comment: So how to covert it to System.String?

Comment: I've described one method to convert from `std::string` to `System.String` right there in the answer. Did you read the answer fully?

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I tried your method but its giving error like:  1. 'c_str' : is not a member of 'std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>'... 2. 'gcnew' may only be used to create an object with managed type.... 3. 'String' : ambiguous symbol 
4.'^' : cannot use this indirection on type 'String'

Comment: @amritaJaiswal : What is contained in the `std::vector`? If the `vector` does not contain `std::string`s then you'll have problems. Please post the exact code that you have which leads to the errors. The answer above is based on a short analysis of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/556754/761170) post. So, if your code is different from it, further changes may be required to get it to work correctly.

Comment: @amritaJaiswal : If you're using the code exactly as it is, then I guess the line `typedef std::string String;` may cause some problems as `String` is a CLI type, so try using some other identifier for the `typedef` statement.

Comment: yes it was giving error so I declare as string instead of String.

Comment: which identifier shall i use?

Comment: @amritaJaiswal : Please use a non-conflicting name for the identifier like `StrVal`. So the `typedef` statement would look like `typedef std::string StrVal;` and the one following it would be `typedef std::vector<StrVal> CSVRow;`. Hopefully that should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks.. I have done whatever you told. Now its giving error  'c_str' : is not a member of 'std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>'  
at this line   String^ myString= gcnew String(*i.c_str());

Comment: I tried with this   String^ myString= gcnew StrVal(*i.c_str()); and for this also its giving error as-1. gcnew may only be used to create an object with managed type...2.  'c_str' : is not a member of 'std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Ty,_Alloc>'

Comment: Could you please edit the question & post the **exact** code that you're trying to compile?

Comment: @ Bhargav Bhat: Thanks for your time. But I got other source code to read CSV files data and it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you are implementing appears to be flawed. It is possible to have commas embedded within CSV fields, which the answer doesn't seem to recognize.

Perhaps you know for a fact that your data will never have embedded commas, in which case there shouldn't be an issue. But I have an older version [that I've posted online](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/files/reading-and-writing-csv-files-in-mfc) that demonstrates some additional steps that should be taken.