# How to parse and store team information from files into classes?

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have a few files that contain nba teams and their starters, and i need to add this information into my program then do a few tasks with them.

I am currently stuck on being able to parse the files.

The files look like this:

`Team Name, Point guard, shooting guard, small forward, power forward, center`

For example:

`Chicago Bulls, Derrick Rose, Kyle Korver, Luol Deng, Carlos Boozer, Joakim Noah
Denver Nuggest, .. etc.`

I want to be able to only add the names of the team, point guard, and small forward, and I'm not sure on how to do that.

What i have so far:

```
 17         ifstream* myIN = new ifstream();
 18         myIN->open(filename.c_str());
 19 
 20         string teamName;
 21 
 22         *myIN >> teamName;
 23         
 24         while(!myIN->eof()){
 25                 TEAM.push_back(teamName);
 26                 //TODO
 27         }
```

I am looking into using "find()" to find each comma, but i don't know how to only record the information before and after the first comma, and after the 3rd comma.

Any sort of guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many languages (or their standard libraries) have a `split` function whose purpose is to tokenize (or split) a delimited string. Unfortunately, the C++ `std::string` class does not offer a `split` function.

However, `boost::split` offers this capability; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/236976/1497596) and other answers to the question [Splitting a string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c).

By the way, your file format appears to be what is commonly referred to as a [CSV File](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values). You may also find this question of interest: [How can I read and manipulate CSV file data in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415515/how-can-i-read-and-manipulate-csv-file-data-in-c)

Comment: That is exactly how my file is set up. The last link helped tremendously, thank you!

Comment: @Ey0o - Glad my answer helped! By the way, in addition to [accepting my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), you might also consider [upvoting my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) as well (that is clicking the upward-pointing triangle icon). And as a user new to StackOverflow, you may also find the entire [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) quite informative and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really really common (and luckily for you, simple) case of parsing using `tokenizing`.

Here, the different fields you need are separated by the same character: `,`

Please see this [stackoverflow question about tokenizing in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c) for more information.

Also, don't forget to remove unnecessary spaces on your tokenized elements (except the first one)

Comment: Wow, great! I've never herd of it before, i will give it a try. Thank you for your help!