# Formatting CSV files in C++

Tags: c++, csv

I am trying to take a simple CSV file, split it line-by-line, and print it to the console. Currently I am getting an error when compiling and want to know if I am missing something obvious.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc , char** argv) {

    std::string line;
    std::ifstream infile(argv[1]);

    if (infile) {

        while (getline(infile, line)) {

            std::istringstream ss(line);
            std::string token;

            while(std::getline(ss, token, ",")) {

                std::cout << token << "\n";

            }

        }

    }

    infile.close();
    return 0;

}
```

The error I am getting is as follows.

```
csv.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
csv.cpp:41:46: error: no matching function for call to 'getline(std::istringstream&,
std::string&, const char [2])'
csv.cpp:41:46: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/string:55:0,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/locale_classes.h:42,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/ios_base.h:43,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ios:43,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.7/istream:40,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.7/fstream:40,
             from csv.cpp:21:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/basic_string.tcc:1070:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::getline(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, _CharT)
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/basic_string.tcc:1070:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
csv.cpp:41:46: note:   deduced conflicting types for parameter '_CharT' ('char' and 'const char*')
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/string:54:0,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/locale_classes.h:42,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/ios_base.h:43,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ios:43,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.7/istream:40,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.7/fstream:40,
             from csv.cpp:21:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/basic_string.h:2792:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::getline(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&, std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/basic_string.h:2792:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
csv.cpp:41:46: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided
```

Comment: I read that thread and it makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: After seeing Igor's answer, I realized that the other thread probably was unrelated to your issue -- I've retracted the close vote.

Answer (score 3):

The third parameter of `getline` is a `char`, not a `char*`. Make it `getline(ss, token, ',')` - note single quotes.

Oh, and beware CSV fields `"like"",""this"`  (in case you wonder, this is a single field with the value of `like","this`). There's more to CSV syntax than meets the eye.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should use a library for CSV munging... perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415515/how-can-i-read-and-manipulate-csv-file-data-in-c) is useful.